# Hidden form field using none model forms

Tags: python, django

When I'm using model forms I can exclude a field from showing by using a Meta class and **exclude**. However, with standard **none model** forms this does not work. I want to hide a field call amount and populate on init. How?

```
amount = forms.FloatField()
```

well I have tried to first exclude like this...

```
class Meta:
    exclude = ('amount',)
```

but this does not seems to work on none model forms.

Comment: only 1-line code ? what else have you tried ? Maybe looking up docs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `forms.ModelForm` to override the init

```
class YourForm(forms.ModelForm):
    amount = forms.FloatField() 

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(YourForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['amount'].widget = forms.HiddenInput() 
        self.fields['amount'].initial = ''
```

Comment: if you use `ModelForm` only, it will really not work but if you extend it with the `forms.MOdelForm`. YOu can use both of them.